# Using Pandas to operate across rows that are specified by another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this problem in Pandas, but I have not been able to find it after spending hours with `df.pivot()` and `df.groupby()`

I am working with a dataframe like this:

```
uid               col1        col2      col3   aggregate this value
100002891-100003074 A      1         X         1
100002891-100003074 A      3         Y         11
100002891-100003074 B      1         X         7
100002891-100003074 B      1         Y         5
100002891-100003074 B      2         X         2
100002891-100003074 B      2         Y         16
100002891-100003074 B      3         X         10
100002891-100003074 B      3         Y         7
100006186-100006393 A      1         X         1
100006186-100006393 A      1         Y         1
100006186-100006393 A      3         X         2
100006186-100006393 B      2         X         1
100006186-100006393 B      2         Y         2
100042231-100042624 B      1         X         2
100042231-100042624 B      1         Y         1
```

For each unique `uid`, I want to compute the ratio of `aggregate this value` across the `X` and `Y` entries in `col3` while preserving the other category columns. The resulting dataframe will be ~1/2 the length of the input (but probably longer than 1/2 because some UIDs are only associated with 1 `aggregate this value` entry).

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

I've tried to generate a dataframe with `uid`, `X` and `Y` columns using df.pivot(), but that gives alternating rows with NaNs.

I've also tried using df.groupby().transform(lambda x) but I have not figured out how to craft a lambda expression that works in this case.

Edit:
The expected output should look like this:

```
uid               col1        col2         X/Y Ratio
100002891-100003074 A      1                   1
100002891-100003074 A      3                   11
100002891-100003074 B      1                   1.4
100002891-100003074 B      2                   0.125
100002891-100003074 B      3                   1.42
100006186-100006393 A      1                   1
100006186-100006393 A      3                   2
100006186-100006393 B      2                   1.5
100042231-100042624 B      1                   2
```

BTW, the method needs to be somewhat performant because it will apply to >100M rows

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there expected output?

Comment: if you can provide the expected result (logic), then we should be able to help achieve this.

Comment: Thanks @AndrejKesely, I've edited it with the expected results

Comment: @nllero Looking at the output, is the last row (`100042231-100042624 B      1                   1.5`) correct? Shouldn't the ratio be `2`? Also... can there be 2 or more `X` or `Y` for each `uid`/`col1`/`col2`. If yes, what should be the result in that case?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes, that's correct. Thanks for the catch: I updated the table. To your other question, there should only be 1-2 values for each X-Y combination.

Comment: **>100M?** I'm just curious if your data are somehow sorted. Suppose the x, y values are at opposite ends of the database, if there's only one of them, then it looks like we need to group all the data before doing any math. What if we can assume that corresponding data are in a window of a fixed width?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
col = "aggregate this value"


def fn(g):
    if len(g) != 2:
        return g[col]

    g = g.set_index("col3")
    return pd.Series(g.loc["X", col] / g.loc["Y", col])


out = (
    df.groupby(["uid", "col1", "col2"])
    .apply(fn)
    .droplevel(level=3)
    .reset_index(name="X/Y Ratio")
)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
                   uid col1  col2  X/Y Ratio
0  100002891-100003074    A     1   1.000000
1  100002891-100003074    A     3  11.000000
2  100002891-100003074    B     1   1.400000
3  100002891-100003074    B     2   0.125000
4  100002891-100003074    B     3   1.428571
5  100006186-100006393    A     1   1.000000
6  100006186-100006393    A     3   2.000000
7  100006186-100006393    B     2   0.500000
8  100042231-100042624    B     1   2.000000
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Can you explain what the `droplevel` is doing here, and why it is important to `set_index("col3")`? Those steps are confusing to me. I appreciate it!

Comment: @nllero It's because the `.groupby` adds automaticaly one index level (which we don't need here, so hence `.droplevel`)